# Remove link from witihn current menu list item

Tags: jquery, href, listitem

I have a menu, which like most, adds "current-menu-item" to the class of the list item when the current page matches up to the menu item selected. However, I want to remove the link from the current menu item. I'm using the following code, but with no joy. Can anyone point out what is going wrong:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
    jQuery(".current-menu-item li:has(a[href=''])").remove();
});
```

Comment: please update the html code or fiddle

Comment: you want to know about what to pass inside href equality check conditions.?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
jQuery('.current-menu-item li a').removeAttr( 'href' );
```